# Fill merged cells in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have a data frame in an excel sheet which i have put in a google sheet for reference [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTEs4Wh-YTOMUHE1SE7K_pw5NZzhinOhvY2wimFx9fM/edit#gid=0)

`Sheet1` contains the dataframe and expected output contains the expected output.

I want the dataframe with merged cells to be filled with their respective values for the first 3 columns.

What I have tried is below:

```
filtered_data = work_sheet_data[work_sheet_data['Account Name']!="NaN"]
pivot = filtered_data.pivot_table(index=['Account ID','Account Name','Contract ID','Code value'], values='TB', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

print(pivot)
pivot.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Work_Sheet2')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can reproduce your input `pivot` with :

```
from io import StringIO
import requests

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" \
      "1nTEs4Wh-YTOMUHE1SE7K_pw5NZzhinOhvY2wimFx9fM/" \
      "export?format=csv&gid=0"

pivot = (
    pd.read_csv(StringIO(requests.get(url).text))
        .rename(str.strip, axis=1).ffill().set_index(
            ["Account ID", "Account Name", "Contract ID", "Code value"])
)
```

But the expected output is not clear/precise (*at least for me*). So, I'll give three possible options :

1. For visual purposes, you can tell pandas to not sparsify the [*MultiIndex display*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html?highlight=sparsify#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) :

   ```
   with pd.option_context("display.multi_sparse", False):
           print(pivot)

                                                       TB
       Account ID Account Name Contract ID Code value    
       12334Abc   test1        tese3       1            1
       12334Abc   test1        tese3       2            1
       12334Abc   test1        trsr2       3            1
       12334Abc   test1        trsr2       4            1
       12334Abc   test1        trsr2       5            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         6            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         7            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         8            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         9            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         1            1
       3456def    test2        tr3         2            1
   ```
2. For an Excel spreadsheet (*without formatting*), just [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

   ```
   pivot.reset_index().to_excel("output.xlsx")
   ```

   [image]
3. For an Excel spreadsheet (*with formatting*), use the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

   ```
   css_style = "font-weight: bold; text-align:center"

   out = (
       pivot.reset_index().style
           .applymap(lambda x: css_style, subset=pivot.index.names)
   )

   # out.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment to make a spreadsheet
   ```

   [image]